# bluetooth controller not working after sending few messages

Tags: bluetooth

I have a simple bluetooth code to activate a relay.
it is from an old project and it used to work fine, but I was sending just bit in the past, this time I have to send strings.
With this code I can send six command and then the device doesn't respond anymore. when I stop the application suddenly all the commands "un-executed" before are executed by the relay board. If I change the size of the buffer it seems to have some effect on the number of messages I can send.
I am using an old phone a controller with Android 2 and API 10
Any idea where I should investigate?
Thanks

```
public class Menuuu extends Activity {
BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter;
BluetoothSocket mmSocket;
BluetoothDevice mmDevice;
OutputStream mmOutputStream;
InputStream mmInputStream;
String a;
Editable b;

final byte[] buffer = new byte[2048];
private ToggleButton T1;

private static final String TAG = "MyActivity";


public void write_buf(byte[] buffer) {
    try {
        mmOutputStream.write(buffer, 0, 1024 );
        mmOutputStream.flush();
    } catch (IOException e) { }
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    final ToggleButton T1 = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.Button1);
    T1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
    if (T1.isChecked()) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            buffer[0] = 'r';
            buffer[1] = 'e';
            buffer[2] = 'l';
            buffer[3] = 'a';
            buffer[4] = 'y';
            buffer[5] = ' ';
            buffer[6] = 'o';
            buffer[7] = 'n';
            buffer[8] = ' ';
            buffer[9] = '0';
            buffer[10] = ' ';
            buffer[11] = '\r';
            buffer[12] = '\n';
    }
        if (!T1.isChecked()) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                buffer[0] = 'r';
                buffer[1] = 'e';
                buffer[2] = 'l';
                buffer[3] = 'a';
                buffer[4] = 'y';
                buffer[5] = ' ';
                buffer[6] = 'o';
                buffer[7] = 'f';
                buffer[8] = 'f';
                buffer[9] = ' ';
                buffer[10] = '0';
                buffer[11] = '\r';
                buffer[12] = '\n';
        }
        write_buf(buffer);
        }
});



void findBT() throws IOException
{
    mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();

    if(!mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled())
    {
        Intent enableBluetooth = new    Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
        startActivityForResult(enableBluetooth, 1);

    }

    Set<BluetoothDevice> pairedDevices = mBluetoothAdapter.getBondedDevices();
    if(pairedDevices.size() > 0)
    {
        for(BluetoothDevice device : pairedDevices)
        {
            if(device.getName().equals(a)) 
            {
                mmDevice = device;
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    UUID uuid = UUID.fromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb"); //Standard //SerialPortService ID

    mmSocket = mmDevice.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(uuid);

    mmSocket.connect();
    mmOutputStream = mmSocket.getOutputStream();
    mmInputStream = mmSocket.getInputStream();


public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu){
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    MenuInflater h= getMenuInflater();
    h.inflate(R.menu.hardmenu,menu);
    return true;
}
```